# How can I recreate a table as index-organized?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

In an Oracle 10g database I would like recreate a table (maintaining all of its data) as an index-organized. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Can you take downtime?  Or does the table need to be online while doing so?

Comment: Downtime doesn't matter, the table can be taken offline without an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RENAME EXISTING_TABLE TO OLD_HEAP_TABLE;

CREATE TABLE NEW_IOT_TABLE AS
 ([COLUMNS FROM EXISTING TABLE]
  CONSTRAINT NEW_IOT_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY ([PK_COLUMNS FROM EXISTING TABLE]
 )
 ORGANIZATION INDEX;


INSERT INTO NEW_IOT_TABLE
SELECT * FROM OLD_HEAP_TABLE;

COMMIT;

RENAME NEW_IOT_TABLE TO EXISTING_TABLE;

-- DROP OLD_HEAP_TABLE when you're sure it all worked.
```